# Dynamic Pivot in OPENJSON

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have below JSON data.

```
{
"Id": "001",
"EMP_Id": 203,
"DEP_Id": 4126,
"CreatedOn": "2020-07-20T03:52:26.6918267-04:00",
"CreatedBy": "Test"
}
```

[image]

I need to convert it into the below format, but my JSON values will be dynamic, I will not know what columns in Key I will get it.

[image]

Below the sample code:

```
DECLARE @Json  NVARCHAR(200)
SET @Json = '{"Id":"001","EMP_Id":203,"DEP_Id":4126,"CreatedOn":"2020-07-20T03:52:26.6918267-04:00","CreatedBy":"Test"}'
SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM OPENJSON(@Json)
```

Kindly help me to achieve it.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: The problem with not knowing what data in is in your JSON also means you don't know what the data types are; that is a problem unto itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to dynamically build the explicit schema needed for the `OPENJSON()` call. You need to execute `OPENJSON()` with the default schema to get the `key` names and data types:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @Json nvarchar(200)
SET @Json = '{"Id":"001","EMP_Id":203,"DEP_Id":4126,"CreatedOn":"2020-07-20T03:52:26.6918267-04:00","CreatedBy":"Test"}'
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)

-- Explict schema
SELECT @stm = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
   QUOTENAME([Key]), 
   CASE 
      WHEN [type] = 0 THEN CONCAT(N' nvarchar(200) ''$."', [key], N'"''')
      WHEN [type] = 1 THEN CONCAT(N' nvarchar(200) ''$."', [key], N'"''')
      WHEN [type] = 2 THEN CONCAT(N' int ''$."', [key], N'"''')
      WHEN [type] = 3 THEN CONCAT(N' bit ''$."', [key], N'"''')
      WHEN [type] = 4 THEN CONCAT(N' nvarchar(max) ''$."' , [key], N'"'' AS JSON')
      WHEN [type] = 5 THEN CONCAT(N' nvarchar(max) ''$."', [key], N'"'' AS JSON') 
   END
), N',')
FROM OPENJSON(@Json)

-- Execute statement
SET @stm = CONCAT(N'SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (', @stm, N')')
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@json nvarchar(200)', @json
```

Result:

```
Id  EMP_Id  DEP_Id  CreatedOn                         CreatedBy
---------------------------------------------------------------
001 203     4126    2020-07-20T03:52:26.6918267-04:00 Test
```

Comment: Thank you @Zhorov, great solution.